# Connection at Atatürk airport

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, turkey, maltese-citizens

I am a Maltese national travelling from Malta to Turkey, with a connection flight at Atatürk airport 6 hrs later to Dubai with Emirates.

Since the flights are with different  airlines and I would need to collect luggage, do I need to go through passport control to connect to the Emirates flight?

Also, do I need a visa for transit?

Comment: Is this a single or separate booking?

Answer (score 2):

> Since the flights are with different airlines and I would need to collect luggage do I need to go through passport control to connect to the emirates flight?

**Yes**, to collect baggage you must go through passport control first.

> Also do I need a visa for transit?

**Yes**, baggage collection is a landside activity hence you will be entering Turkey and will require a visa. You are eligible for an e-Visa that you can easily get online or at kiosks at the Airport.

Your [e-Visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/) will be

> Number of Entries: Multiple-Entry
>
> Visa Fee: Gratis (No Fee)

Hurray!

This answer relies on your statement that You would need to collect baggage. If you booked with a single booking that then used multiple codeshare airlines your baggage might be / can be checked through - please ask them about the status first. In that case you won't need to go through immigration hence no visa no baggage collection required.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the flights are with different airlines and I would need to collect luggage

Note that this only applies if it's in separate **bookings**. If it was a single booking, it'll be automatically checked through.

As per the other answer, to enter Turkey you can get an e-visa (on the Website or at the kiosks), using either your passport or ID card.